# "write using a black pen" Is the usage correct?

Tags: grammar, syntax

**Hi.**

I have a question regarding the following two sentences:

A: Please **write *using*** a black pen when providing further information under this section.
B: Please **review** the document ***using*** the latest version of the software XXX.

Are the two sentences grammatically correct?
Based on my linguistic knowledge, I would say the sentences are awkward.

I would say that the sentences should be corrected as follows:
A
1. Please write **with** a black pen when ...
2. Please write ***by* using** a black pen when ...

B
1. Please review the document **with** the ...
2. Please review the document ***by* using** the ...

In sum, what I confused about is the structure "S+V using" because someone said that there is nothing wrong with the two sentences.
I just feel like they are grammatically erroneous.
Besides, for me, the sentences do not look like sentences that are transformed into participial constructions.

Hopefully, someone could help me out with this question.
If sentences A and B are grammatically correct, please explain to me why the two sentences are correct syntactically/linguistically.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To be picky, I think you want people to use "black ink", not "black pen".  E.g. a pen could be black, but contain red ink.

Comment: @Ray You are right. But that is not the point that I want to discuss here. Maybe mentioning the pen is not really a good idea because people would like to discuss the usage of pen and ink. Well, let's forget the pen/ink issue first. For the time being, I just want someone who can explain to me whether the sentence structure that I mentioned is grammatically correct or not. Do you have any comments about this question?

Comment: I strongly disagree that "a (color) pen" is not idiomatic. Strictly interpreted it would be more accurate to say "(color) ink," but I see it written this way (use a black pen) on forms _all the time_ and for me it's quite clear that it refers to the ink color. Maybe this is an American vs. British thing?

Comment: Both your examples strike me as idiomatic and neither as awkward. You could shorten the first to: **Please use a black pen.....** without changing the meaning.

Comment: My wife managed recruitment for a health-related lab job where the ability to strictly follow written instructions was a key part of the required skill set. At the top of the form was printed 'Please complete this form in BLACK ink'. At sift time, guess what happened to the forms completed in blue, green or (yes!) red ink?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase, `using a black pen` is a participle phrase. It modifies the verb `write` and indicates how the writing is to be done. In that sense, the phrase acts as an adverb.

The sentence can be inverted (but feels less natural) by saying,

> *Using a black pen*, please write when providing further information under this section.

This in part feels awkward because the point of the sentence is to provide information, not to write. It seems more appropriate to say,

> Using a black pen, provide further information under this section

The second sentence you ask about feels quite natural to me. I believe it's also grammatically correct for the same reason; `Using the latest version of the software XXX` is a participle phrase.

But overall, just because a sentence is grammatically correct, does not mean that it is the best sentence to use. As the comments have suggested, other forms seem more appropriate.

Comment: OP does not have comment privileges. I am posting their comments here. Comment by OP: Thank you for your thorough explanation.
Based on your example, the participle phrase is originally an adverb clause, right?
If so, there must be an adverb that is omitted to form such a participle phrase.
What is the original structure of the following sentence?

**"Using a black pen, provide further information under this section."**

Comment: Is it By using a black pen, you provide further information under this section?
If not, what is the original adverb that is omitted for "_ using a black pen, provide further ..."?

I also found an example from the website.
It reads "You are able to create a new account on English Language Learner Stack Exchange using a login from Stack Exchange."
In this case, the V-ing using also serves as the function of a participle phrase as the other examples that we discussed above, right?